# How granular should we get when tagging the Sitecore version

Tags: discussion, community-guidelines

In my opinion, one of the most important pieces of information you can give me to help me solve your issue/challenge is the Sitecore version you are using. On SO, we already have a few version related tags, both for major and minor versions. Are we happy with those? Should they still say Sitecore8.1 or is v8.1 enough seeing as we're on the Sitecore StackExchange site? What about including the revision/update? Naming convention?

Answer (score 12):

I've been removing a lot of Sitecore 8.1 tags earlier today, as none of the questions involved - in my opinion - were specific to the actual version.

I'm a bit worried we'll end up in a situation where questions get marked for 8.1 or 8.2 for instance, while being relevant to users of Sitecore 6 as well.

However - I also agree - the version matters; in many instances. But should it be a tag?  or should it be something we ask to be clarified (when we feel it could be relevant) in the question text itself?

I'm leaning towards that. That we ask for clarification/update the question text - rather than it being a tag - since we can't really do a "sitecore-6.2-sitecore7.2" tag either.

But excellent question; let's get the ball rolling and see what people think :-)

Comment: I believe asking for clarification on to the Version of Sitecore in question is better than using tagging. Instead, leave tagging for things like "exm", "fxm", modules names, design pattern names, dare even I suggest pipeline names? pipeline names as tags would be cool from a facet pov.

Comment: @MarkCassidy, I just saw your tag edit on one of my questions, and I think you made the right call. I also think we should look at [how other SE communities have solved the same problem and follow suit](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/639/2007). I like the simplicity of how the wordpress site has tags for specific versions, but only uses them when a question is related to that *specific* version.

Comment: I think the general consensus of this post is; we add version information to the post itself - if and when necessary. This is also the advise we're getting from @Robert Cartaino (below)

Answer (score 9):

Unless the question is about the *subject* of the version itself, tagging questions with version numbers is usually incidental to what is actually being asked. If the version number ***is*** relevant for getting the correct answer, that information should be included **in the body of the post.**

But I rarely find it useful to categorize questions broadly by version number — tags are for search. If knowing the version number ***is*** important to getting the correct answer, you definitely should *not* be using tags to provide important context.

Answer (score 3):

I agree - I don't think it is useful to have tags for each version number. If your question is version specific, include it in the question not via a tag.